# MS Access Complex Query Help (Cross-Join typ)

Tags: sql, ms-access, unpivot

Greetings: I am working on a variant configurator for a part numbering system.

I have two tables which define the characteristics of the numbering system. Null means the combination is invalid and to be skipped.

**Table 1:**

```
PowerSize | Model A | Model B | Model... | Input A | Input B | Input... | Temp A | Temp B | Temp... |

20HP | S10 | S30 | null | 6P | null | 5R | 40C | 50C | null|

200HP |null|null| E10 | 6P | 3R | null | null | 50C | 55C|


**Table 2:**

Model | Normal Duty | Heavy Duty | Light Duty | No Filter | Sine Filter |

S10 | N | null | null | N | S |

S30 | null | H | null | N | null |

E10 | null | null | L | null | S |

I need a query (or series of queries) that explodes the valid combinations:

**Result Example**


**Model | PowerSize | Input | Temp | Duty | Filter |**

S10 | 20HP | 6P | 40C | N | N |

S10 | 20HP | 6P | 40C | N | S |

S10 | 20HP | 6P | 50C | N | N |

S10 | 20HP | 6P | 50C | N | S |

S10 | 20HP | 5R | 40C | N | N |

S10 | 20HP | 5R | 40C | N | S |

S10 | 20HP | 5R | 50C | N | N |

S10 | 20HP | 5R | 50C | N | S |

S30 | 20HP | 6P | 40C | H | N |

S30 | 20HP | 5R | 40C | H | N |

S30 | 20HP | 6P | 50C | H | N |

S30 | 20HP | 5R | 50C | H | N |

E10 | 200HP | 6P | 50C | L | S |

E10 | 200HP | 3R | 50C | L | S |

E10 | 200HP | 6P | 55C | L | S |

E10 | 200HP | 3R | 55C | L | S |
```

and so forth.

I tried using Dlookup but wasn't able to sort it out.

I tried DLookup but it didn't handle the null's as exclusions (at least I couldn't figure out how to do the criteria for it to work)

Can someone give me some pointers or examples? Greatly appreciated in advance.

Comment: in short convert Table1 & Table2 from cross-joins back to normal tables. then join the normalized tables on model.  I can show joining the normalized tables, but I ran out of time debugging the code that I have to customize to each table that needs un-crossing.

Comment: @mazoula That's a good idea and one I wished I would have done. I ended up writing VBA script to read from an aux table that lists each column name, created a dozen or so union queries with ~10 queries in each. Performance is pretty good this way, just took too long to build and test the code. Thanks for the thought -- that method probably would have been faster initially, although wouldn't be as dynamic when future "options" (i.e. fields) are added.

Answer (score 0):

use null check, example : `Not IsNull(DLookup(`

Answer (score 0):

I built a VBA script using two loops to build a set of union queries based on a auxiliary table containing all fields, and then manually joined each union query to create the completed list (about 50,000 lines long). Performance is good this way, much better than DLookup methods I had tried. If I had to do it over again, I may have setup SQL Express and used unpivot or cross join for this workflow as that probably would have been less time consuming than researching alternative ways and eventually writing and testing a VBA routine.

```
Dim aux_table, main_table, query_sort_name, main_table_catsource, str_query_category_subloop, str_query_category_union  As String


'Define Name
aux_table = "AuxTable_Series"
main_table = "VC3_Series_vs_Input_Duty_Env_Filter_DBR_Cert"
main_table_catsource = "VSD_Series"
query_sort_name = "autoqry_Series_"
    
'Load Aux_table to recordset
Set rs_AuxTable = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(aux_table)
    
'Loop through each Aux Table Column/Field
For Each aux_field In rs_AuxTable.Fields
    
    'Set Aux Column Name
    
    'MsgBox aux_field.Name
    
    'Get Count of Records for Column
    Set rs_count = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT COUNT(" & aux_field.Name & ") AS RecCount FROM " & aux_table)
    'MsgBox rs_count.reccount
    
    
    rs_AuxTable.MoveFirst
    i = 0
    str_query_category_union = ""

    Do While i < rs_count.reccount
        'MsgBox rs_AuxTable.Fields(aux_field.Name)

        'Same Category Union Query
        
        str_query_category_subloop = "SELECT " & main_table & "." & main_table_catsource & "," & main_table & "." _
        & rs_AuxTable.Fields(aux_field.Name) & " AS " & aux_field.Name & " FROM " & main_table & " WHERE " _
        & main_table & "." & rs_AuxTable.Fields(aux_field.Name) & " Is Not Null"
        'MsgBox rs_AuxTable.Fields(aux_field.Name)
                   
        If i = 0 Then
            str_query_category_union = str_query_category_subloop
        Else
            str_query_category_union = str_query_category_union & " UNION " & str_query_category_subloop
        End If
        
        rs_AuxTable.MoveNext
        i = i + 1
        
    Loop
    rs_AuxTable.MoveFirst
    i = 0
    
    'MsgBox str_query_category_union
    
    CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef query_sort_name & aux_field.Name, str_query_category_union
         
Next
      


rs_AuxTable.Close
rs_count.Close
Set rs_AuxTable = Nothing
Set rs_count = Nothing
Set aux_field = Nothing
```

End Sub